# MySqlBulkUploader inserts Null value from CSV to MySql c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have CSV File consisting 10 rows and 4 cols.I have to bulk upload csv records in MySQL Table. My code is creating rows successfully but each cell of MySql Table is displaying NULL Instead of Original Value as in CSV.I had also tried Command "Load data local Infile" but same results...What I have to do?
Here is my c# code

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase UploadExcel)
    {
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + UploadExcel.FileName);
        UploadExcel.SaveAs(FilePath);
        FilePath = FilePath.Replace("\\", "/");
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        myConn.Open();
        string TableName = "testTable_TEMP";
        var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(myConn);
        bl.TableName = TableName;
        FilePath = FilePath.Replace("\\", "/");
        bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
        bl.LineTerminator = "\n";
        bl.FileName = FilePath;
        bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
        var count = bl.Load();
        myConn.Close();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: why are you changing the folder delimiter character in the `FilePath` variable? Have you checked the `FilePath` value? does the file exist?

Comment: Yes,Firstly File is saved in appropriate folder then I am accessing the file. And file is placed on Physical Path also.

Comment: If the server is windows most likely that `FilePath.Replace("\\", "/");` would return a non existing file.

Comment: Its Working Now.Thank You bradbury9 for your Valuable solutions.

Comment: Glad to help, putting an answer with the cause of the problem so you can mark it as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is windows most likely that FilePath.Replace("\", "/"); would return a non existing file.